# how to determine transaction key in OMJJ？

Tags: sap-erp

I want to know how the accounting code in SAP automatic account determination is determined. I read that the accounting codes in many accounting vouchers are different from those in `OMJJ`, and the number and types of accounting codes are not the same. For example, the accounting voucher generated by a standard purchase order has two accounting codes but only one `OMJJ`. The accounting vouchers generated by the storage of out-of-contract purchase orders have many accounting codes, but not so many `OMJJ`. I found a lot of information and tried it their way. How is the accounting code determined? Or if there are any links and materials you can send me to see.